# CMake cannot find XMLRPC package

Tags: 16.04, cmake

I'm trying to run CMake to build project (it's private, so I can't paste full content of CMakeLists.txt) on Ubuntu 16.04. CMake fails on this line:

```
find_package (XMLRPC REQUIRED c++2 client)
```

with error message:

```
XMLRPC was not found.  Make sure the entries XMLRPC_* are set.
```

I have installed libxmlrpc packages, but that doesn't help.

```
$ sudo apt list --installed | grep -i xmlrpc

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in 
scripts.

libxmlrpc-c++8-dev/xenial,now 1.33.14-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libxmlrpc-c++8v5/xenial,now 1.33.14-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libxmlrpc-core-c3/xenial,now 1.33.14-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libxmlrpc-core-c3-dev/xenial,now 1.33.14-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libxmlrpc-epi-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 0.54.2-1.1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
libxmlrpc-epi0/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 0.54.2-1.1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
libxmlrpc-epi0-dbg/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 0.54.2-1.1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
libxmlrpcpp-dev/xenial,now 1.11.16-3 amd64 [installed]
libxmlrpcpp0d/xenial,now 1.11.16-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Which package requires CMake? Maybe I need to manually point CMake on one of already installed packages?

And generalizing the question: as I understood from [this manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man7/cmake-modules.7.html) `find_package` works only with listed packages. How to find `apt` package for any of these CMake packages?